# how to get images from external xml and view it on my app

Tags: android

i want to show images from external url listed in external xml ("similar" to picasa API).

from where i need to start, there is an app sample like this, do i can read is source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start from seeing DOM and SAX parser for parsing XML in android
- Here is a nice code for SAX parser:
  http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html
- Then see sample codes to fetch remote images in image view

Hope it will give you an idea